# SelectedIndexChanged event of dropDownList not firing in Update Panel

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel

SelectedIndexChanged event of dropDownList not firing in Update Panel and also set AutoPostBack="true".

Below is my Design Code:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
 <ContentTemplate>
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_TypeofCampaign" runat="server"  CssClass="form-control" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddl_TypeofCampaign_SelectedIndexChanged" AppendDataBoundItems="true" ViewStateMode="Enabled" EnableViewState="true" >
<asp:ListItem Text="Select" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text="Email" Value="Email"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text="SMS" Value="SMS"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text="Voice SMS" Value="Voice SMS"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanel1"
DisplayAfter="1">
<ProgressTemplate>
<div id="IMGDIV" runat="server" align="center" style="visibility: visible; vertical-align: middle; position: absolute; background-color: #fafbf6"
valign="middle">
 <asp:Image ID="Image001" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/assets/img/ajax-loader.gif" />
 </div>
 </ProgressTemplate>
 </asp:UpdateProgress>

   </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Code behind:

```
protected void ddl_TypeofCampaign_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
    FillTemplates();
    btn_Preview.Visible = false;

}
```

My page Load code.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        FillGrid();
        FillTypeofSourcing();
        FillCampaignNames();
        FillTemplates();

    }
}
```

Fill Template method where I am getting templates name base on selection.

```
 protected void FillTemplates()
{
    if (ddl_TypeofCampaign.SelectedItem.ToString() != "Select")
    {
        bo.Para1 = ddl_TypeofCampaign.SelectedItem.ToString();
        bo.Para2 = "Stage1";//StageValue in TemplateMasterInfo Table
        DataTable dt = bl.Get_Templates(bo);
        ddl_TypeofTemplateName.DataSource = dt;
        ddl_TypeofTemplateName.DataTextField = "TemplateName";
        ddl_TypeofTemplateName.DataValueField = "TemplateId";
        ddl_TypeofTemplateName.Items.Clear();
        ddl_TypeofTemplateName.Items.Add(new ListItem("Select", "0"));
        ddl_TypeofTemplateName.DataBind();
    }
    else
    {
        ddl_TypeofTemplateName.Items.Clear();
        ddl_TypeofTemplateName.Items.Add(new ListItem("Select", "0"));
        ddl_TypeofTemplateName.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: show your `page_load` code

Comment: I had updated my question and also mention page load code. @Webruster

Comment: where are you loading this dropdown ?

Comment: any error in Console?

Comment: I had removed all update panel and progress bar and when I select dropdown list then getting error like this. Validation of viewstate MAC failed. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that <machineKey> configuration specifies the same validationKey and validation algorithm. AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster. @Webruster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Page Tag I mention **viewStateEncryptionMode="Never"** and I am using Visual Studio 2013. Below is my Page Tag details.

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="ViewCandidate.aspx.cs" Inherits="ViewCandidate" validateRequest="false" enableEventValidation="false" viewStateEncryptionMode="Never" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `Trigger` to your Update Panel like shown as below

```
   <Triggers>
     <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddl_TypeofCampaign" 
EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />    
    </Triggers>
```

UPDATE

```
       <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server"> 
    <Triggers> //this is missing in your code posted
     <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddl_TypeofCampaign" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" /> 
   </Triggers> 
     <ContentTemplate>mydropcode </ContentTemplate> </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: I had added your code into update panel  ContentTemplate in that but getting errror: Element 'AsyncPostBackTrigger is not a know element. This can occur if there is compilation error in the web site or the web.config file is missing. @Webruster

Comment: <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
      <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddl_TypeofCampaign" 
EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />    
    </Triggers>  
   <ContentTemplate>mydropcode
  </ContentTemplate>
 </asp:UpdatePanel>. @Webruster

Comment: Now error is not coming but still not firing and I kept break point code behind select index change break point also not working. @Webruster

Comment: @zahed you need to add the `AsyncPostBackTrigger` under `Triggers` like as follows `updatepanel` --> `Triggers` --> `AsyncPostBackTrigger`

Comment: I added your update answer not firing any think and drop down also not filling. @Webruster